# A basic reduced homology isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology

How do you prove the isomorphism $\tilde{H}_{n}(X/A,A/A)\cong\tilde{H}_{n}(X/A)$ for reduced homology groups?  Is it just a matter of seeing that chains into the point $A/A$ end up being trivial in the latter group?

Comment: You should tell us which definition of reduced homology groups (absolute and relative) is used here. Why do you consider $\tilde H_n (Z, \{z\}) \approx  \tilde H_n (Z)$ only for $Z = X/A$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It comes from the reduced long exact sequence of the pair $(X/A,A/A)$. In fact you have that $\widetilde{H_n}(A/A)\cong 0$ for all $n$.

Comment: Oh duh, right..